# Link tag in Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Ok, I am brand new to ruby and Sinatra and I am embarrassed to say I cannot for the life of me find out how to use a link tag in Sinatra.  I just need to link, from my index.erb, to a static page, about.html.  `<a href="about.html">About</a>` is not working.  How can I do this?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like:

```
<a href="/about.html">About</a>
```

You're going to want to locate this about.html file in the /public folder of your application.
If you want to overwrite using that location for another one, you can do so with `:public_folder` and is fairly well described at: http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html

I hope that helps.

Comment: [http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html)  I would recommend this as a good initial resource to get your bearings.